# WPF array of strings - Binding to resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I'am trying to create an array of strings which will be set by a static reference to the project's resource file (I use this for localization):

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="FormatTranslation">
    <sys:String>{x:Static p:Resources.Yes}</sys:String>
    <sys:String>{x:Static p:Resources.No}</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

Of course the code above does not work, it just shows the referencce as string.

How can I bind those values to the string entities?

--- Update 1 ---

The array is defined in

```html
<UserControl.Resources>
```

This is the line where I'am referencing the array as a StaticResource to use it as ConverterParameter

```html
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RowData.Row.IsLandscapeFormat, Converter=StaticResource BCBCT}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource FormatTranslation}}"/>
```

Comment: Add the snipped you use this Array please.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Please see Update 1

Answer (score 4):

Add the Static values directly to your array.

```
<x:Array Type="sys:String">
  <x:Static Member="p:Resources.Yes"/>
  <x:Static Member="p:Resources.No"/>
</x:Array>
```